# Login using two interfaces with Retrofit

Tags: android, api, retrofit

I have two interfaces that don't have the same attributes and that i need them to login using Retrofit. How to implement the other interface to use the same button?
I want to use this login method for both interfaces IEnfant and IAssistant :

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


           IEnfant iEnfant= APIClient.getClient().create(IEnfant.class);


           iEnfant.login(editText1.getText().toString(),editText2.getText().toString()).enqueue(new Callback<Enfant>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(retrofit2.Call<Enfant> call, Response<Enfant> response) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"enfant"+response.body().getNom(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CategoriesActivity.class));
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(retrofit2.Call<Enfant> call, Throwable t) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"'error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.v("tag!!!!!!!!!!","error"+t.getMessage());

                }
            });
```

I mean i need to do many callbacks in one activity, is that possible?
here is my two interfaces:

```
public interface IEnfant {
   @GET ("api/eLogin")
   Call<Enfant> login (@Query("username") String username, @Query("mot_de_passe")  String motDePasse);

}

public interface IAssistant {
   @GET ("api/aLogin")
   Call<Assistant> login (@Query("username") String username, @Query("mot_de_passe")  String motDePasse);

}
```

Comment: Please provide more details ? Both interfaces code. And which method you want to use in second Interface?

Comment: Check my edited post please

Comment: You need to create 2 different retrofit instances and use either IEnfant or IAssistant. or you just use on interface with 2 different login methods